# facebook api, is event id universally unique

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

The user's event data is as below. I'm wonder the id `157881474402440` is unique among all events (private, public, belong to any person) in Facebook graph since I'm intending to use it to export to a calendar system as the UID of event (I'll append it with something like "_facebook"). Tks

```
"events": {
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "Return match vs Wollongong", 
        "start_time": "2013-08-10T14:00:00+1000", 
        "end_time": "2013-08-10T17:00:00+1000", 
        "timezone": "Australia/Sydney", 
        "location": "Wentworth park field 1", 
        "rsvp_status": "attending", 
        "id": "157881474402440"
      }
    ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every object on facebook has unique object id.  you can verify it by getting the event details from two different facebook accounts having access to the event.

Comment: you can look at that url with the same access token you had:
https://graph.facebook.com/157881474402440 

It will give you details about this unique id.